# AngularJS - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I wanted to rewrite my existing code, but I failed as I run into this error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.routes due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
```

My working snippet:

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])
   .config(function() {});
```

My rewritten snippet (this one fails):

```
(function () {

  // use strict mode to write clean code!
  'use strict';

  // This configures the routes
  var RouteProvider = function () {

  };

  // init the config
  angular.module('app.routes', [])
    .config(['', RouteProvider]);

}());
```

I have created a Plunker for this: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rfMKaXZTdB0O3f8TKhlX?p=info)

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an empty string into your `.config` call - this is effectively telling Angular you want to inject a service with a blank string as the name into your config function. This doesn't exist, so you get an unknown provider error - a pretty unclear one at that, because it tries to show you the name of the service, but it's blank, so you just end up with `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:` and nothing else!

Your `.config` call should look more like this:

```
// init the config
  angular.module('app.routes', [])
    .config(RouteProvider);
```

You don't need the array syntax if you're not actually injecting anything into the function.